# Wildcard Pattern Matching in Make

Tags: makefile, riscv

Here is my project structure.

```
| - src
     | - boot
           | - table.s
           | - boot.s
     | - machine
           | - revb
                | - memmap
                | - vars.s
     | - os
     | - utils
           | - ...lots here
```

I am grouping features by folder, and have a special folder for machine specific code, link scripts, anything.

The problem I am having with make is that I can't seem to get the Pattern match to work.

> The below runs and builds the .o files.

```
#This gets repetative as every file needs to have a recipe by itself.
$(TARGET_DIR)/hash.o : $(SRC_DIR)/utils/hash.s machine
    @echo "compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo "assembly dump $@"
    $(DUMP) -D $@ > $@.list
```

> The below does NOT work. It doesn't run any of the commands.

```
#if this works that would be perfect every folder/file will be a recipe!
$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.s machine
    @echo "compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo "assembly dump $@"
    $(DUMP) -D $@ > $@.list
```

**Nothing runs at all**, For some reason no files seem to match that pattern.

> I have also tried this.

```
# if this works, it would be a bit annoying as this is per feature recipe/target.
$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/boot/%.s machine
    @echo "compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo "assembly dump $@"
    $(DUMP) -D $@ > $@.list
```

**Edit**
full makefile for reference

```
CFLAGS = -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32
CC = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-as
LINKER = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-ld
DUMP = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump
COPY = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-objcopy
SRC_DIR = src
TARGET_DIR = target
MACHINE_FILES_DIR = machine
TARGET_MACHINE = revb


# vizoros : $(TARGET_DIR)/%.o
#   $(LINKER) $(TARGET_DIR)/boot.o $(TARGET_DIR)/table.o $(TARGET_DIR)/os.o $(TARGET_DIR)/hash.o -T $(TARGET_DIR)/memmap -o $(TARGET_DIR)/$@.elf
#   $(DUMP) -D $(TARGET_DIR)/$@.elf > $(TARGET_DIR)/$@.list


$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/boot/%.s machine
    @echo "compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo "assembly dump $@"
    $(DUMP) -D $@ > $@.list

machine: folders
    cp -r $(SRC_DIR)/$(MACHINE_FILES_DIR)/$(TARGET_MACHINE)/. $(TARGET_DIR)

folders:
    mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)

.phony: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)
```

Comment: What does "not work"? Are these *complete* Makefiles, or is there more to them? Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @DevSolarthe I clarified more.

Comment: You provided a template rule on how to generate .o files from .s files. Where do you tell the Makefile which .o files to generate?

Comment: @DevSolar is this not it? `$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o : ...` Maybe that's where I'm mistaken.

Comment: @DevSolar how would i do that?

Comment: Hmmm... this seems like a more fundamental lack of understanding what `make` does. Make rules tell `make` how to satisfy dependencies. When you `make myapp.exe`, `make` will look for a rule on how to generate `myapp.exe`, or any `%.exe`. That rule will tell `make` what dependencies need to be satisfied first (like object files), and the commands on how to build `myapp.exe` once the dependencies are satisfied (usually *from* those dependencies). If those dependencies do not exist as files, `make` checks for rules for *those*. This is what your wildcard rule is: A rule how to create `.o` files.

Comment: (ctd.) But you're missing a "top" rule you want to *invoke* (like `myapp.exe`), which has all the `.o` files of your project as a dependency. Then you probably want a rule `all: myapp.exe` as the first rule in your Makefile, so `make` (first rule) and `make all` (`all` rule) both do the same as `make myapp.exe`. Traditionally, you list all your source files, or have `make` list them for you: `SOURCES:=$(wildcard ...)`. Each has pros and cons. Then you create a list of all *object* files, e.g. `OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))`. Then `myapp.exe: $(OBJECTS)`, and you're almost there. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar there is a top level you can see it commented out in the full example. I am providing a minimal example on why I can't get my obj files to build. I'm no where near "there", I've been doing this on and off for 2 weeks. I've tried doing `Sources=$(wildcard **/*.s)` I tried `Sources=$(wildcard *.s). I tried `Sources=$(wildcard boot/*.s). You asked me for a minimal example. This is it. And now I get told there is a problem with not having everything? But then if I post everything I need a minimal example. This feels like circles on stack overflow. I'm too dumb to figure this out :(

Comment: @DevSolar the reason I don't want to post more, is then there is too much I need to tackle. I'm trying to ask one question with one topic. That's what other people complain about. Getting to my top level scares me, because it includes all the `.o` files to be included in the 1 line with `$(LINKER), which scares me because that is wayy different. I wanted to tackle that, when i had those obj files buit.

Comment: The idea behind an example is not to post *your code*. It is to build a scaled-down *example* that is still sufficient to **reproduce** the problem -- exactly so I (and everyone else) can take the example, run it locally, get the same effect that's confusing you, and verify that my explanation *solves* the problem. It doesn't have to be a Makefile that does Risc stuff, it doesn't have to be useful for anything else *but* reproducing the problem. I know this can be difficult at times, but it is an *important* debugging skill. Without such a minimal, reproducable example, we're left guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your other question, you are expecting too much fancy capability from make.  Make is a very simple tool.  It will not go looking around your directories for files that could be built.  It will build only exactly what you ask it to build.  It will not infer matching files based on heuristics: it will match only exact strings.

Make always works *backwards*: it starts with the final target you ask it to build and finds a rule that can build that.  Then it looks at each of the prerequisites of that final target and finds a rule that can build each one of those.  Then it looks at any prerequisites of each of the prerequisites of those, etc.  Once it has built (or found source files for) all the prerequisites of a target, it builds that target, then walks back up until finally it builds the final target you asked for.

In your makefile above you've commented out the "final target" you want built (`vizoros`), so of course make will not build it.

I'm just going to give you a makefile that solves your problem... if you want to understand what it does please consult the GNU make manual.  Note I haven't actually tried this, I just wrote it here.  Also note I omitted the whole `machine` thing because I don't understand what it's supposed to do and you didn't really define it.

```
CFLAGS = -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32
CC = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-as
LINKER = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-ld
DUMP = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump
COPY = riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-objcopy
SRC_DIR = src
TARGET_DIR = target
MACHINE_FILES_DIR = machine
TARGET_MACHINE = revb

# Find all .s files under SRC_DIR

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name \*.s)

# Use VPATH with a list of directories to be searched for

VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(SRCS)))

# Convert all .s files into .o files directly under TARGET_DIR
# First strip off the directory, then convert

OBJS := $(patsubst %.s,$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

# Define the final target and provide all the object files as prerequisites

$(TARGET_DIR)/vizoros.elf : $(OBJS)
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(LINKER) $^ -T $(TARGET_DIR)/memmap -o $@
        $(DUMP) -D $@ > $(@:.elf=.list)

# Define a pattern rule to build an object file in TARGET_DIR
# The source file will be searched for via VPATH

$(TARGET_DIR)/%.o : %.s
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        @echo "compiling $<"
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
        @echo "assembly dump $@"
        $(DUMP) -D $@ > $@.list

# It must be .PHONY, not .phony: make, like all POSIX tools, is
# case-sensitive

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)
```

References:

- [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)
- [`=` vs `:=` variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html)
- [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)
- [`dir` and `notdir` functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)
- [`sort` and `patsubst` functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
- [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html)
- [Substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html)
- [Automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)
- [Phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)

Also note you had an error in your compile command; you were missing the `-c` option which tells the compiler to generate an object file rather than a final executable file.

Comment: I never would have came up with that in a million years. I needed to make only one modification for the machine part. I will read all that documentation. I noticed that an obj file was created even without the -c command. so I thought it was fine, but that might explain some problems I was having with jumps to other addresses. Thanks!

Comment: @christopherclark: You might have stumbled over one of `make`'s *inbuild* rules. (There are predefined rules for how to turn e.g. `.c` into `.o`, which can give somewhat surprising results if you aren't aware of them and haven't defined such yourself.)

Comment: As @DevSolar says you likely were using a built-in rule.  It should have been very obvious since the built-in recipes do nothing but compile code while your recipes do lots of other things like dump assembly etc.